# React Firebase update database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ant-design-pro

I'm displaying customer information and using [ant design editable text](https://ant.design/components/typography/) to edit profile fields.

I'm driving myself crazy with this one as I can't pass the key & value through my function and into the state object.

Any suggestions on how to get this working would be muchappreciated.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: I'm not able to get either the key/value in my state update - they're coming back undefined

Comment: You're only passing one value to the function `updateClient()`

Comment: Ah man, I didn't realise I needed to pass the value, I've updated and it now works. Thanks guys